# the isset function work through a conditional?

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn PHP, and i have a form, with only name field

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="POST">
    <h3>Name</h3>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="send">
</form>
```

add the isset method so that the error will not mark me "
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs"

```
<?php

$nombre = isset($_POST["name"]);

if($nombre=="nat"){
    echo "good job";

    } else{
        echo " dont say nothing ";
        }

?>
```

but this always prints "good job"

I mean, the condition always true, no matter what you write in the input

but if I remove the isset method, the conditional works as it should, but show me the "Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs"

Comment: Where is your `isset()` call?

Comment: I don't think this code can do what you say. Are you sure you didn't make the common mistake of writing `if ($nombre = "nat")`? If you use `=` instead of `==` it's an assignment, not a test.

Comment: Another common mistake is to write `if (isset($_POST['name']) == "nat")`.

Comment: That should be `if (isset($_POST['name']) && $_POST['name'] == "nat")`.

Comment: Please show the actual code that's not working as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I did not put the isset, but I already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset()` just returns `true` or `false`, it doesn't return the value of the variable. So when the parameter is set, your condition is turning into:

```
if (true == "nat")
```

This is successful because of PHP's type juggling. When you perform a comparison with a boolean, it converts the other value to a boolean, and any non-empty string converts to `true`.

If you changed it to:

```
if ($nombre === "nat")
```

the `===` comparison doesn't do type juggling, and it would always fail.

You can do this:

```
$nombre = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : "";
```

Then your comparison will work as expected.

Comment: thanks, with this code if it works, but every time I load the default form it shows me "dont say nothing", what is this about men?

Comment: should I start the variable $ _POST ['name'] as null so that it does not enter the condition until it has a value?

Comment: You should have `if (isset($_POST['send']))` around all the code that's intended to run only after the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

So `$_POST` and `$_POST['name']` is always set after send the form, but its content might be empty. `!empty()` already checks whether the value is set, you can also use this version:

```
if(!empty($_POST["name"]) and $_POST["name"] == "nat" ){
    echo "good job";
} else{
    echo " dont say nothing ";
}
```

See docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: What does your first line have to do with the question? You seem to be assuming they wrote `isset($_POST)` instead of `isset($_POST['name'])`. But since the question doesn't show the code, how can you know that?

Comment: And you haven't explained why the test `$nombre == "nat"` is always succeeding (I can't understand it, either).

Comment: "And you haven't explained why the test $nombre == "nat" is always succeeding (I can't understand it, either "                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                        
that is the problem, even if it does not send anything, it always succeeding and shows it ("good job"), since I have loaded the form